# puppet-rspec how to use undef param

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec, puppet

In my init.pp manifest i have parameter:

```
$database_host = 'db.localhost.com',
```

and have a simple check for that parameter:

```
if $database_host == undef {
    fail('You must specify database_host')
}
```

Also I have added rspec test for that paramter:

```
context 'db conf require database_host' do
  let :params do {
    :database_auth => 'local',
    :database_host => :undef,
  }
  end
  it { should raise_error(Puppet::Error, /You must specify database_host/) }
end
```

But for some reason test shows that nothing was raised:

```
 expected Puppet::Error with message matching /You must specify database_host/ but nothing was raised
```

If i set database_host to undef in init.pp and remove this param from test then it works. 
But How can i override param from init.pp to undef

```
$database_host = 'db.localhost.com'
```

in my test to get it working?

Comment: The reason that does not work is because the `fail` function is from Puppet and you are working within Ruby/RSpec here. The extended matchers from RSpecPuppet have no knowledge of Puppet functions. As for how to get it working, that I don't know, but you may have success mocking the Puppet function as a Ruby method.

Comment: So basically this: https://github.com/Accuity/rspec-puppet-utils#mockfunction